# python pandas: count no of users falls in the both categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of the following format

```
user    category
1         A
1         B
1         A
2         B
3         B
2         B
```

Now I am trying to count how many unique users are in each category and in both categories. So for above table I have  `A=1, B= 3 and A&B = 1`

The following code gives me no of users in each category:

```
df.groupby(['category',]).count()
```

But this is not what exactly I am looking for. Any help or clue will be appreciated.

Comment: @Zero, I believe the question is how do you also output A, B = 1, i.e. unique count of intersection of A & B users.

Comment: Yes, i have edited the question. thanks

Comment: Mohamamd, did one of these solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for pivoting and then use [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html), for number of intersection add [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and get length:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['user','category']).size().unstack()
print (df1)
category    A    B
user              
1         2.0  1.0
2         NaN  2.0
3         NaN  1.0

print (df1.count())
A    1
B    3
dtype: int64

print (len(df1.dropna()))
```

Or:

```
print (df.notnull().all().sum())

1
```

If need all users in all categories:

```
print (df1.dropna().index.tolist())
[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. The output is in dictionary format. Intersections are denoted by a tuple key.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A'], [1, 'B'], [1, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [2, 'B']], columns=['user', 'category'])

result = df.groupby('category')['user'].agg(lambda x: set(x)).to_dict()

for i, j in itertools.combinations(result, 2):
    result[x] = result[i] & result[j]

result = {k: len(v) for k, v in result.items()}

print(result)

# output
# {'A': 1, 'B': 3, ('A', 'B'): 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `groupby` By using  `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.user,df.category)
Out[604]: 
category  A  B
user          
1         2  1
2         0  2
3         0  1


pd.crosstab(df.user,df.category).replace(0,np.nan).count()
Out[612]: 
category
A    1
B    3
dtype: int64
pd.crosstab(df.user,df.category).replace(0,np.nan).count().min()
Out[613]: 1
```